# How to detect the number of uploaded files and their names before uploading from client side by javascript or jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, client-side

I want to upload multiple files and have a file called test.php with this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
var myVar;
$('form').submit(function(){
    myVar = setInterval(ajax, 1000);
});
var ajax = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test2.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(ajax_result){
            $('.result').html(ajax_result);
            if (!ajax_result) {
                clearInterval(myVar);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
};
});
</script>
</head>
<body style="width:100%; height:100%;">
<form action="test2.php" target="iframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>" value="fil" />
    <input name="file[]" type="file" multiple />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe"></iframe>
<div class="result" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and a file called test2.php with this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_FILES['file'])){
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++) {
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'a/'.$_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
}
}
if (isset($_SESSION[$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . 'fil'])) {
     var_dump($_SESSION[$key]);

} else echo false;
?>
```

Now I want before sending files to server to detect the number of files selected via their names in the client side.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var numberOfFilesAboutToBeSubmitted = $("[name='file[]']", this ).prop("files").length;
```

});

Note that you are not submitting any files with your ajax request, it has no association with your form at all.

Also note that this doesn't work in IE < 10

Comment: my problem solved by your guide. very thanks to you good friend